# org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Column with name «name» isn't present in this «ResultSet» Hibernate with PostgreSQL JDBC

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, hibernate-native-query

As the subject says, I have that error in Hibernate 5 with a PostgreSQL DB.

The query that Hibernate returns to me is:
`SELECT u.email, u.password FROM utenti u WHERE u.email = ?` (so it's correct)
and the table is:

```
utenti(email (pk), password, nome, cognome, datanascita, sesso)
```

Moreover, I get another error:
Exception starting filter struts2

```
Unable to load configuration. - action - file:<path>/NetBeansProjects/DBIIProject/target/DBIIProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:15:34
```

My `struts.xml` is:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>

    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false"/>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>

    <!-- Cambio l'estensione delle Action da .action a .do -->
    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="do" />

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
        <action name="Login" class="org.altervista.cdpjavaexamples.dbiiproject.actions.LoginAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success">index.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">login.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="Logout" class="org.altervista.cdpjavaexamples.dbiiproject.actions.LogoutAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success">index.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="PasswordRecovery" class="org.altervista.cdpjavaexamples.dbiiproject.actions.PasswordRecoveryAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success">password_recovery.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">password_recovery.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

My pom.xml is:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.altervista.cdpjavaexamples</groupId>
    <artifactId>DBIIProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>DBIIProject</name>

    <properties>
        <struts2.version>2.3.24.1</struts2.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.2</log4j2.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.24.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.1207.jre7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-junit-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.16.v20140903</version>
                <configuration>
                    <stopKey>CTRL+C</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>8999</stopPort>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>xwork.loggerFactory</name>
                            <value>com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.log4j2.Log4j2LoggerFactory</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/</webAppSourceDirectory>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <descriptor>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</descriptor>
                    </webAppConfig>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Finally my Hibernate's files are:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping class="" file="" jar="" package="" resource="org/altervista/cdpjavaexamples/dbiiproject/model/Utenti.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <!-- Mappatura classe - tabella -->
  <class name="org.altervista.cdpjavaexamples.dbiiproject.model.Utenti" table="utenti">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
          Descrizione della classe
      </meta>
    <!-- Chiave primaria -->
    <id column="email" name="email" type="text"/>
    <!-- Campi -->
    <property column="nome" name="nome" not-null="true" type="text"/>
    <property column="cognome" name="cognome" not-null="true" type="text"/>
    <property column="password" name="password" not-null="true" type="text"/>
    <property column="sesso" name="sesso" not-null="true" type="boolean"/>
    <property column="datanascita" name="dataNascita" not-null="true" type="date"/>
  </class>

  <!-- Query -->
  <sql-query name="selectEmailPassword">
      <return class="org.altervista.cdpjavaexamples.dbiiproject.model.Utenti"/>
      <![CDATA[
        SELECT email, password FROM utenti WHERE email = :email
      ]]>
  </sql-query>
  <sql-query name="selectNomeCognomePassword">
      <return class="org.altervista.cdpjavaexamples.dbiiproject.model.Utenti"/>
      <![CDATA[
        SELECT nome, cognome, password FROM utenti WHERE email = :email
      ]]>
  </sql-query>
  <sql-query name="emailExists">
      <return class="org.altervista.cdpjavaexamples.dbiiproject.model.Utenti"/>
      <![CDATA[
        SELECT * FROM utenti WHERE email = :email
      ]]>
  </sql-query>
  <!-- Fine query -->
</hibernate-mapping>
```

[image: Project's structure]

I have already searched in the forum, but the solutions I found weren't good to solve my problem.

Comment: It's nome. ;)
I typo it when I translated it from italian to english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used native SQL queries in Hibernate mapping with `<sql-query>`. These kind of query have to work with native SQL dialect specific to the database on which this query could be executed.  So if you make an error in SQL code, or change the database, your query might not work. There's no point to use native SQL query in your code, and they should be replaced with [*named* queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e6392).

> Using a mapping document can be configured using the `<query>` node.
>   Remember to use a `CDATA` section if your query contains characters
>   that could be interpreted as markup.

Here's an example of such query

```xml
<query name="selectEmailPassword"><![CDATA[
    from org.altervista.cdpjavaexamples.dbiiproject.model.Utenti as u
    WHERE u.email = :email
]]></query>
```

Parameter binding

```java
Query q = sess.getNamedQuery("selectEmailPassword");
q.setString("email", email);
List<Utenti> l = q.list();
```

Comment: I want to use native queries so that the DBA can change them without have to touch Hibernate ;)

Comment: DBA can only change the query if it's located on the server. He can't change the application code.The client's queries have to change by the developer.

Comment: For this reason I want to put the queries inside Utenti.hbm.xml e not inside the code..

Comment: Understood. But why if I use Criteria objects it works?
For example this works without problems:
`Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Utenti.class);
            cr.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                .add(Projections.property("email"), "email")
                .add(Projections.property("password"), "password"))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("email", email))
                .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Utenti.class));
            List<Utenti> results = cr.list();`

Comment: You can also use Criteria instead of native SQL, even better without projections and transformations.

Comment: There's another way to select only some columns with Criteria without using Projections?

Comment: If you have another question you can ask it on another page. If this answer helped you to solve your problem, please mark it as accepted. I don't see a reason to continue this discussion.

Comment: Sure, but I still get the error if I use named native queries.

Answer (score 0):

You define `<return class="org.altervista.cdpjavaexamples.dbiiproject.model.Utenti"/>` and it looks like the class has `name` property (e.g. marked to used "name" column). When your SQL is executed hibernate tries to fill the entity but ResultSet does not have column to fill the name.

Comment: So, how can I get only some columns with named queries?

Comment: Your SQL query should include all columns mentioned in the entity

Comment: All you declare in your entity. Or you can declare another entity with less columns

Comment: Ok, I understood. But why if I use Criteria I don't get that error?

And, instead, I get an error if I try to retrive all the data for a row?

Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Utenti.class)
                                    .add(Restrictions.eq("email", email))
                                    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Utenti.class));
            List<Utenti> results = cr.list();
            exists = !results.isEmpty();

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. At the end I used Criteria objects to perform queries.